# SharePoint 2010 Team Project Collections Error!

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, tfs

I have recently migrated our current tfs and sharepoint production system onto a test enviroment to more recent versions. The new installation is a single server farm with sql, tfs and sharepoint, i also run the changeserverid for tfs as i have been told TFS stores GUIDS in the databases - this was run to allow the test enviroment to run allongside the production enviroment.

Problem! TFS urls working fine, find the project sites etc and everything seems to work fine!

SharePoint web part - 
when i try and go to the projects i get the following error

"There are no accessible team projects in this team project collection. Contact your team foundation server administrator"

Note i have run the sharepoint fix connections procedure with zero errors but didnt fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already answered here but ill copy the guide:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282953/tfs-2010-sharepoint-web-part-error

> 1.Open Team Explorer
>
> 2.Right click your [TeamProject]
>
> 3.Select Team Project Settings > Group Membership
>
> 4.Select [TeamProject]\Readers group and click properties
>
> 5.Add your user or team groups

also a more detailed guide:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181475(v=vs.100).aspx

> Team project settings and properties vary from team project to team
> project. The team project properties are set from the Team menu in
> Visual Studio and define settings for groups and permissions which
> identify members of the team project and their access rights. For
> example, one software developer may have access to change document X
> in a team project but not document Y, while another software developer
> involved in the same team project may have access to change both
> documents X and Y. Assigning groups helps to establish the various
> sub-teams within the team project and to better manage the required
> tasks. Team project settings also include the virtual hierarchical
> groupings for artifacts within a team project. The classification
> structure may include the life cycle iterations that make up a team
> project and the components or features of a team project. Work items
> and other artifacts such as test cases, may also be classified against
> the structures/hierarchies to make for easier tracking and reporting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181234(v=vs.90).aspx

not saying that you didnt back it up properly! but just incase here is a guid on msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552295.aspx

**EDIT**

for the error:

> This site doesn't have a default Team Project. You can explicitly
> select a specific Team Project. This web part is not configured
> properly. Click here to configure web part in tool pane.

**cause**

> At it's core this is a communication problem between SharePoint and
> the Team Foundation Server, and there may be any number of reasons for
> it, including network connectivity problems. This may also be caused
> by missing or incorrect Portal Settings for the Team Project in
> question, or by missing or incorrect Alternate Access Mappings in
> SharePoint. Finally, it may be caused by missing permissions for the
> [TEAM FOUNDATION]\SharePoint Web Application Services group to the
> team project.

**solution**

> You should first verify proper connectivity between the TFS
> application tier machine(s) and those hosting SharePoint. Then, using
> the Team Foundation Server Administration Console, verify that the
> SharePoint Web Applications entry for the Application Tier and
> SharePoint Web Application in question are established and working.
> You can use the "Repair Connection" option to confirm this:
>
> 1.Open the Team Foundation Server Administration Console
>
> 2.Expand the Application Tier in question (the one hosting the Team Project Collection and Team Project with the problem)
>
> 3.Highlight the SharePoint Web Applications node.
>
> 4.In the SharePoint Web Applications list, highlight the appropriate connection and then click "Repair Connection"
>
> While you are here, verify the membership in the Service Accounts for
> SharePoint Web Applications as well.
>
> If the "Repair Connection" is successful, next verify the Portal
> Settings for the Team Project in question. You access this by
> connecting to the Team Project using Team Explorer. Then, right-click
> the Team Project name and select "Team Project Settings..." followed
> by the "Portal Settings..." option. Ensure the values here are
> correct.
>
> You may also need to update your Alternate Access Mappings in
> SharePoint (see the More Information section below for details on
> this).
>
> Also verify that in the “Extension for SharePoint Products” in TFS
> Administration Console section, make sure that the “Integration
> Target” column is pointing to the new or fully qualified domain name
> that you expect in the Team Web Access URL for the TFS Sharepoint
> portal.
>
> To modify:
>
> - Click and highlight the row, select “Modify Access”.
> - Then update the “URL for Team Foundation Server” accordingly.
> - Click OK, and then test to see if the TSWA URL is now updated.

other solution if fails follow on here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2451685

Comment: Thank you for that worked though now i have another error! "This site doesnt have a default team foundation server instance, you can explicitly select a team foundation server - this web part is not configured properly"

Comment: just update the answer

Comment: Thank you for all your help with this! fixed it this morning also another good troubleshooting step is to actual see if the reporting service is granted in http://localhost/reports !! all the steps proved useful! thank you :)

Comment: no probs happy to help